# is it possible to hide email adress in javax.mail.MimeMessage?

Tags: java, email, email-client

I'm using the following code to create and send an email `to someTo@bla.com`:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("someone@bla.com", "From Me"));
```

And when I receive the mail I see (in outlook, for example) : `From Me <someone@bla.com>`

Is it possible to hide the email address? I would like to see the full email address only when the receiver hits "Replay" but not before.

Comment: Isn't that the mail Server side configuration you talking about that you want to change ?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the sender's address from the recipient?

Comment: @ProphesyAwaits - I believe it is receiver-side configuration. Either in the mail client, or the receiving mail server, but in either case, it is not sender-side.

Comment: @cdeszaq : But what he is asking, it seems like he wants to send the address, just he wants that mail server or the mail client to manipulate it in a way that it is not shown at the receiver's end at first place, on which one doesn't have any control. Any one can use any mail client to see his or her's mails. So either you can completely hide your email or you can make your email public, so that the recipient can see it.

Comment: @ProphesyAwaits, I agree. I was just making the distinction between sender and receiver mail servers, and noting that the sending server _definitely_ can't hide it (without proxying anyways), but the receiving server _might_ be able to, since it could limit connections to only certain clients, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to hide the address of the sender when you (your program) is the sender. Some email clients may have the ability to do that, but in general it is probably a bad practice because it makes it harder to tell who sent the email, making it easier for spamers and phishers.

One way you *could* hide your email address would be to use a proxy service that sends and receives emails on your behalf and acts as a simple forwarding proxy (this is what craigslist does), but that starts to drift into the real of sketchy practices.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.  That is a configuration option usually on the users mail client.  It is there to help users avoid PHISHING scams and other unscrupulous email attacks.